# Ruby on Rails SQL Injection - Building a query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sql-injection

I'm resolving all the SQL Injections in a system and I've found something that I don't know how to treat.

Can somebody help me?

Here is my method

```
def get_structure()
   #build query
   sql = %(
           SELECT pc.id AS "product_id", pc.code AS "code", pc.description AS "description", pc.family AS "family", 
                  p.code AS "father_code", p.description AS "father_description", 
                  p.family AS "father_family"
           FROM products pc
           LEFT JOIN imported_structures imp ON pc.id = imp.product_id
           LEFT JOIN products p ON imp.product_father_id = p.id
           WHERE pc.enable = true AND p.enable = true
   )
   #verify if there is any filter
   if !params[:code].blank?
     sql = sql + " AND UPPER(pc.code) LIKE '%#{params[:code].upcase}%'"
   end
   #many other parameters like the one above
   #execute query
   str = ProductStructure.find_by_sql(sql)
end
```

Thank you!

Comment: This won't solve your issue, but does make things more readable. When having large blocks of text consider using [heredoc](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Here+Documents). Some IDEs also adjust syntax highlighting based on the provided tag. In this case `<<~SQL` or `<<~'SQL'` if you don't want string interpolation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`Arel`](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/rails/arel/Arel) which will escape for you, and is the underlying query builder for ActiveRecord/Rails. eg.

```
products = Arel::Table.new("products")
products2 = Arel::Table.new("products", as: 'p')
imported_structs = Arel::Table.new("imported_structures")
query = products.project(
  products[:id].as('product_id'),
  products[:code],
  products[:description], 
  products[:family], 
  products2[:code].as('father_code'),
  products2[:description].as('father_description'),
  products2[:family].as('father_family')).
  join(imported_structs,Arel::Nodes::OuterJoin).
    on(imported_structs[:product_id].eq(products[:id])).
  join(products2,Arel::Nodes::OuterJoin).
    on(products2[:id].eq(imported_structs[:product_father_id])).
  where(products[:enable].eq(true).and(products2[:enable].eq(true)))
if !params[:code].blank?
  query.where(
     Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new('UPPER',[products[:code]])
       .matches("%#{params[:code].to_s.upcase}%")
  )
end
```

SQL result: (with `params[:code] = "' OR 1=1 --test"`)

```
SELECT 
  [products].[id] AS product_id, 
  [products].[code], 
  [products].[description], 
  [products].[family], 
  [p].[code] AS father_code, 
  [p].[description] AS father_description, 
  [p].[family] AS father_family 
FROM 
  [products] 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN [imported_structures] ON [imported_structures].[product_id] = [products].[id] 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN [products] [p] ON [p].[id] = [imported_structures].[product_father_id] 
WHERE 
  [products].[enable] = true AND 
  [p].[enable] = true  AND 
  UPPER([products].[code]) LIKE N'%'' OR 1=1 --test%'
```

To use

```
ProductStructure.find_by_sql(query.to_sql)
```

I prefer `Arel`, when available, over `String` queries because:

- it supports escaping
- it leverages your existing connection adapter for sytnax (so it is portable if you change databases)
- it is built in code so statement order does not matter
- it is far more dynamic and maintainable
- it is natively supported by ActiveRecord
- you can build any complex query you can possibly imagine (including complex joins, CTEs, etc.)
- it is still very readable

Comment: I have a few questions/comments. 1) Don't you need to save the `query.where(...)` result (inside the *if* statement) back into the `query` variable? 2) I would instantiate the arel tables by simply calling `Model.arel_table` and in the case you need the alias `Model.arel_table.alias('name')`. 3) I would use `.outer_join(arel_table)` over `.join(arel_table, Arel::Nodes::OuterJoin)`.

Comment: @JohanWentholt 1) No. Arel's [where](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/rails/arel/Arel/TreeManager#where-instance_method) is mutating. 2) The code provided can be used with or without rails (`Arel` only) 3) Yes you could do this

Answer (score 1):

You need to turn that into a placeholder value (`?`) and add the data as a separate argument. [`find_by_sql`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Querying.html#method-i-find_by_sql) can take an array:

```
def get_structure
   #build query
   sql = %(SELECT...)
   query = [ sql ]

   if !params[:code].blank?
     sql << " AND UPPER(pc.code) LIKE ?"
     query << "%#{params[:code].upcase}%"
   end

   str = ProductStructure.find_by_sql(query)
end
```

Note, use `<<` on String in preference to `+=` when you can as it avoids making a copy.